# Video Resize/Crop/Combine on iOS

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, avfoundation

I'm trying for edit videos ( resize/crop/combine ) with AVFoundation on iOS.
There are some references that using only one video.
But I want to add more than 3 videos into a scene like as followings.
http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple6/v4/0f/01/c7/0f01c735-208b-2a6b-e9df-330e884c8daa/screen696x696.jpeg

Please let me know if it is possible to implment above requiremets with AVFoundation.
And if possible, what do i have to reference with?
Or AVFoundation is best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use more than one video, you may want to check out `AVComposition` and `AVMutableVideoComposition`.  The link you posted seems to compose multiple videos next to each other, with adjustable borders.

This can be done with `AVMutableVideoComposition` and `CALayers` on top of each, adjusting the layers' borders and corner radii to get the desired effect.  A google search results in a handy tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: thanks for your reply. now i'm going to put 2+ videos into the scene. I couldn't find in this tutorial. There was only video and image merge.. Can you please help more details?

Comment: Add more video tracks to the composition.  See the guide at https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/AVFoundationPG.pdf.  Page 34 for explanation, 37 for a code example of adding tracks.

Comment: thank you for your help. can i ask just another problem? how can i crop video with transform for several videos and then combine them?

Comment: now i cropped and resized videos. and doing collage now. but export failed sometimes for some files.. some files are ok.. what's the reason?